# How does the server know that API call has been made from the client?

Tags: django, server, client

I am currently reading articles on REST API and how the client and server interaction works. I had a question in my mind which is as follows:

How does the server know that REST API call has been made from the client? (E.g.: I get a notification when a receive a message. So, from that I know I message in my inbox. How does server know about the REST API)

Tried to find it on internet but didn't find any relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite broad, but I've tried to answer it comprehensively below.

**TL;DR:** RestAPIs are not fundamentally different to any traditional web server. They 'listen' for HTTP Requests from Clients *(i.e. the '**API Call**')* on a specified port, and are configured to respond appropriately to valid requests as specified.

---

**How does the server know a 'Request' has been made?**
At root, this has nothing to do with RestAPI, and is entirely a function of the HTTP(S) protocol between Client and Server common to all web traffic.

The (simplified) process works as follows:

1. The **Client** sends a 'Request' from their browser (e.g. a GET request to the URL *[www.example.com/home](http://www.example.com/home)*).

- Now a 'Request' is essentially nothing more than a plain text file specifying a method and protocol that 'requests' the content stored at the specified resource location (e.g. *'GET https://www.example.com/home HTTP/1.1'* ), although some requests (e.g. *'POST'* requests) may also contain content themselves in the 'request body'.
- What is 'requested' will usually be just a plain `HTML` document and associated `CSS`, `JS` as well as other 'static' files like images, but it could also be a `JSON` file - particularly in the context of a RestAPI.

2. The **URL** for every HTTP(S) **Request** is composed of at least two parts in addition to the protocol and method:

- A **host** (i.e. *'www.example.com'*), which is composed of the subdomain *'www'*, the domain *'example'*, and the top-level domain *'.com'*.
- And a **path** (i.e. */home*), which is a unique resource identifier that can be understood by the server and mapped to a specific response.

3. The worldwide set of **Domain Name Servers** will map each **URL** to an appropriate **IP address**, which will be the unique IP address of a Server that is capable of correctly fulfilling the Request.

- This essentially 'routes' the request from the Client to the Server and back over the internet.

4. The **Server** will be continuously 'listening' for requests on a specific set of **ports** (typically port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS) sent to its IP address.

- In the context of a **Django** project in production, this 'listening' will almost always be handled by a dedicated web-server application like `Apache` or `Nginx`, interacting with a gateway interface like `mod_wsgi` or `gunicorn`. This layer is what lets your Django server 'know' a request has been submitted. When you are running your server locally in development, you are doing something very similar without the Apache/Nginx layer, listening to your 'local' IP Adress (127.0.0.1) on port 8000 (the Django development port), but you should not do this in production as (1) it is insecure, and (2) Django is dreadful at serving static files using this method.
- Here, each request is logged by both your web-server application (e.g. Apache) and your Django application. Django will take the **path** of the request, pattern-match it against the URL_PATTERNS you define throughout your project, and attempt to call a **view** function if it successfully matches.
- Assuming the request is valid, the view is configured correctly, and there are no faults with the set-up, Django will then send back an **HTTP(S) Response** to the client, which will usually be a rendered HTML template - or in the context of a RestAPI, it may well be a JSON Response.

5. Finally, if all the above has gone well without any problems, the client's IP Address will be sent the response, and it is then free to do with that response whatever it wishes (e.g. display it in the browser).

---

**Rest API specific considerations**

As noted above, the question of 'knowledge of the request' is not to do with the RestAPI, but instead to do with the traditional HTTP Client-Server set-up.

However, because you ask this question using the **Django** tag, I assume that therefore you are likely to be talking about **Django Rest Framework** specifically, which is a pre-built RestAPI for serving JSON responses within a Django project.

Most importantly, bear in mind that the concept of an **API Call** over the web is fundamentally no different to any other **HTTP Request**, so servers know about API Calls in exactly the same way they know about all HTTP Requests.

The only additional considerations to be aware of here in the context of a RestAPI is as follows:

- **API** stands for **A**pplication **P**rogramming **I**nterface, and is essentially an agreed upon standard for two different computer programmes to talk to each other. This means that while traditional HTML-based HTTP(S) requests-responses can be pretty 'lax' compared to many other areas of programming (e.g. it is fairly accommodating to errors, and will make a lot of non-explicit assumptions when needed), an API-based system is far more restrictive and prescriptive to ensure predictable performance.
- **REST** stands for **RE**presentational **S**tate **T**ransfer, which is a layer on top of HTTP(S) for defining robust quality communication between Client and Server. The main thing to be aware of when dealing with REST is to ensure that there is no 'shared state' between the client and the server: each 'request' and 'response' should be sufficient for serving its purpose in its entirety, and it should not 'presuppose' a specific 'representation' on the receiving end.
- For these reasons, **JSON** is most often used as the means of transmitting information *RESTfully* over a *RestAPI* like Django RestFramework, because it is a very robust, interchangeable and platform/implementation agnostic data-format with a rigorous specification.
- However, there is nothing that stops HTML/XML from being implemented RESTfully, and libraries like Carson Gross's `HTMX` is attempting to do this following the HATEOAS principles *(Hypertext As The Engine Of Application State)*.

So, this is quite a long route to answering your question, but hopefully it does the job of explaining how something like DRF as a RestAPI works and listens out for API Calls. It essentially does so no differently to how any other traditional web server would listen for any HTTP Request, by listening continually on a specified port for HTTP Requests to its IP address.